# Delete all site data in firefox

Tags: firefox

I have 2 google accounts and firefox on startup always logs into the wrong one which really pisses me off. How can I make it log into the first one or forget all data regarding websites to start over?

Comment: If you didn't know, Google gives you an option to log out. No?

Where does it sign you in? Gmail? Sync? AskUbuntu?

Comment: Yea everywhere and maybe you shoulsnt think that people you dont know are stupid automatically. You think i havent signed out? You rhink i havent tried that every time i open firefox?

Comment: I was just making sure. Chill.

Comment: Nick, could you please remove the superfluous info of your emotional state at the time of you writing the question and the comment? (An apology to @SachinKamath who answered your question would be deemed polite too...)  Sachin: drop me a comment [at]Fabby if you don't get one within the next week or so as Nick isn't on-line daily)

Comment: No, it's okay. After all,he's is a 1k reputation guy. I'm fine :)

Comment: this is a questkion about ubuntu since firefox is a program that comes with the distribution. If i asked something about banshee or rhythembox, or one of the other sitloads of bloatware that comes with, would it be on topic?

Comment: im just annoyed of how specific this site is, half of the questions I ask are flagged. This is directly related to ubuntu because ubuntu comes with firefox.  @SachinKamath i appreciate the answer, but when he said "No?" in the "If you didn't know, Google gives you an option to log out. No?" i felt like he takes me as someone who is not aware of something so basic like an option to log out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in Firefox, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. Select how much history you want to clear, I'd suggest you to clear **Everything**.

Next, click the arrow next to Details to select exactly what information will get cleared. Again, check everything present there.

Finally, click the **Clear Now** button. The window will close and the items you've selected will be cleared.

Comment: And thank you for being a gentleman!  ;-)  Worthy of an upvote.